# Is Turing completeness necessary?

Tags: computability, pushdown-automata, turing-completeness

Most programming languages are Turing complete (finite memory blah blah blah), and when we design languages this is a goal.

But is it really necessary? What algorithms do we typically use that *require* Turing completeness? And do most industry software actually require it?

Like what can't pushdown automata do?

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115229/755

Comment: The "blah blah blah" is quite off-putting.

Comment: Turing completeness mandates a kind of loop construct. You would not go very far without loops.

Comment: Worth reading is David Turner's paper on Total Functional Programming. It suggests a model that is more powerful than primitive recursion but still guarantees either termination or cotermination. (Cotermination is the dual notion of termination for non-terminating programs like operating systems.) https://sblp2004.ic.uff.br/papers/turner.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Say that a programming language is **general-purpose** if all computable tasks can be programmed in it. It is worthwhile having such langauges, for the same reason that it is worthwhile having a universal computing machine.

Every general-purpose programming language is Turing complete, because by design it can express the Universal Turing machine.

There are **special-purpose** programming languages that are not Turing-complete. Some examples include database query languages, programming languages in proof assistants, languages that allow only limited resources to be used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following video, as it discusses the questions that David Hilbert asked and resolved by Gödel and Turing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeQX2HjkcNo

Answer (score -3):

Turing complete means no size limits.

For the C language, it’s easy to define an implementation with language-based limits that are way beyond physical limits. So you will never have an actual machine running into the limits. But the limits are there, so C is not Turing complete.

But if the limits are so high that building a machine that runs into the limits is physically impossible, at that point Turing complete or not makes no difference.

Comment: The real issue is not finiteness (no physical computer is infinite). The issue is the computing model.

Comment: Yves, you are completely missing the point. The issue is not finiteness, the issue is that any of those machines has a limit of which _finite_ tapes it can handle. And then read the actual question. It is answered.